# django-registration-redux custom user model login only working via /admin/

Tags: django

I am using a custom user model for my Django project and I can log in via `/admin/` perfectly fine. But when I go to `/accounts/login` and try to log in, it just bounces me back to the login page without logging in. I am using `django-registration-redux` with the simple backend.

Via logging I discovered that the error happens in this method in `django.contrib.auth.__init__.py`:

```
def get_user(request):
    """
    Returns the user model instance associated with the given request session.
    If no user is retrieved an instance of `AnonymousUser` is returned.
    """
    from .models import AnonymousUser
    user = None
    try:
        # 
        # EXCEPTION THROWN ON BELOW LINE
        #
        user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
        backend_path = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        if backend_path in settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS:
            backend = load_backend(backend_path)
            user = backend.get_user(user_id)
            # Verify the session
            if hasattr(user, 'get_session_auth_hash'):
                session_hash = request.session.get(HASH_SESSION_KEY)
                session_hash_verified = session_hash and constant_time_compare(
                    session_hash,
                    user.get_session_auth_hash()
                )
                if not session_hash_verified:
                    request.session.flush()
                    user = None

    return user or AnonymousUser()
```

Any ideas? `/accounts/register/` performs as expected, although I have overridden `RegistrationView`. Perhaps I have to do the same thing for logging in?

**Login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}
<link href="{% static 'css/signin.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-3" align="center">Login</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="id+username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit">Login</button>
    </form>

    Not a member?
    <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register</a>
</div>
    <p>
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

**Urls.py**

```
class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = UserProfileRegistrationForm

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def register(self, form):
    logging.debug("THIS IS MY REGISTER")
    new_user = form.save(commit=False)
    new_user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
    new_user.save()

    login(self.request, new_user)
    logging.debug("Logged in")
    signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                 user=new_user,
                                 request=self.request)
    logging.debug("After signals")
    return new_user

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('base.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name="registration_register"),
    url(r'^accounts/password/change/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name="auth_password_change"),
    url(r'^accounts/password/change/done/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name="auth_password_changed"),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**EDIT:**

I have a temporary fix of throwing a view into login in **urls.py**. Something tells me this is extremely dirty but it seems to work... for now. I'm open to better alternatives.

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', my_view, name="login"),

def my_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'index.html', {})
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
            pass
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {})
```

Comment: You need to use login redirect url in your settings.py file.Read this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `{{ form }}` in your login template, instead of rendering the fields manually. This can show whether the problem is in your template or elsewhere.

In this case, I think that the form fields should be `username` and `password`, not `email` and `password` as you have.

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="id_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
<input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
```